# Appending Nested Lists in Python

Tags: list, nested, append

I have the following question for homework

> Define a function append lists that
>   takes a list of lists and returns a
>   new list containing the sublist
>   values. For example, append lists([[1,
>   2], [3, 4], [5]]) should return the
>   list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and append
>   lists([[1, 2], [3], [[4, 5]]]) should
>   return the list [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]].

I've tried various ways of creating this function in order to append the list so it gives the desired output to no avail so I came here looking for some help. I've found a few other ways of going about this online, but they use extensive methods that we haven't even dabbled in as of yet in my CPSC 121 class. We're limited to the basics in what we've learned.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the basics of what you've learned, i.e., what are the limitations?

Comment: We've gotten to basic list slices i.e. [n:m]
We've also covered basics of appending/removing items from a list and dabbled in loop functions

Comment: `def append_lists(list):
    a = list[:]
    list.append(a)
    print(list)`

Thats the most recent attempt i've tried

Comment: So let me see if I understand: lists([[1,2], [3,4], [5]]) means you have a list of lists where the first list consists of two items with values of 1 and 2, the second list consists of two items with values 3 and 4, etc. ...?

Comment: @cynthia That is correct, and the goal is to break down the nested lists down so that they're part of a new list and no longer nested (i.e. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Answer (score 0):

By now, it is likely that the assignment is gone, but here is a solution:

```
def append_lists(lists):
    output = []
    for l in lists:
        for e in l:
            output.append(e)
    return output
```

This appends each element of each list to the output of the function, which eliminates exactly one level of nesting in the elements.